# Laravel and Vue.js put method using fetch

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm encountering an error with the put method [![enter image description here][1]][1]

I'm using axios for post and fetch for put. I don't know how a put method will work on axios so if anyone could help I would really appreciate it.

**Component.vue script**

```
editItem (item) {
        this.dialog = true
        this.editedIndex = this.departments.indexOf(item)
        this.id = item.id;
        this.department = item.department_name;

      },
  save() {
    const { department } = this
    if (this.editedIndex > -1) {
      fetch('/api/department', {
        method: 'put',
        body: JSON.stringify(this.department),
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json'
        }
      })
    } else {
      axios 
      .post('/api/department', { department })
      .then(response => this.initialize())
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }
    this.close()
  },
```

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $department = $request->isMethod('put') ? Department::findOrFail($request->id) : new Department;

    $department->id = $request->input('id');
    $department->department_name = $request->input('department');

    if($department->save()) {
      return response()->json($department);;
    }
  }
```

**API**

```
Route::get('departments', 'DepartmentController@index');
Route::get('department/{id}', 'DepartmentController@show');
Route::post('department', 'DepartmentController@store');
Route::put('department', 'DepartmentController@store');
Route::delete('department/{id}', 'DepartmentController@destroy');
```

The post method works but not for put as seen with the error posted above.

Comment: fyi, there are axios [Request method aliases](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-method-aliases) on their github

Comment: Thank you for this. I have now made it successfully work.

Comment: Nothing in this question is adding up. Your initial error message has a 404 status but your Postman example has 405 and for some reason, is detecting a GET request. Also, your URLs are different, the first is `/api/department` and the second is `/api/department/`

Comment: Removed screenshot. It was actually a fault of a test select box that also uses get department

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you didn't implement a put method in the backend. The exception indicates that the put request is made, so the problem is probably not related to Axios.

```
Route::put('foo/bar', function()
{
    //
});
```

Edit: 
If you make a PUT request, it's supposed to be sent to an endpoint that concerns a resource (to either create or update). It is an idempotent request, meaning that if you send the request, it will cause the same result regardless whether you sent it once or multiple times.
Please try something like this:

```
Route::put('department/{id}', 'DepartmentController@update')

public function update(Request $request, $id)  {
```

And make sure that the request method adds the id as path parameter in the request.

Comment: I do have an API if that's what you are referring to. The post method works but not for put. I have now posted my API.

Comment: Ok, it's probably related to Laravel, I'll take a look. Btw it's useful to install something like Postman (or any rest client like curl or other) to verify the endpoints if you are uncertain about whether it concerns Axios.

Comment: Could you check if the update makes any difference?

Comment: Thank you very much. I did try postman and this is the result, please refer to the edited question above. It seems like there is indeed a problem with Laravel.

Comment: I'll try your recommendation. EDIT: After putting {id} it became 405 (method not allowed)

Comment: @JimERussel Can you check if you send the id as path param, and that the update function has the correct signature as mentioned in my edited answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204293/discussion-between-trace-and-jim-e-russel).

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**
I have now successfully make it work. I'll share it to everyone in case other people new to laravel and vue might encounter the same problem.

This is now the working code, using axios.

```
save() {
    const { department, id } = this
    if (this.editedIndex > -1) {
      axios 
      .put('/api/department', { department, id })
      .then(response => this.initialize())
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
    } else {
      axios 
      .post('/api/department', { department })
      .then(response => this.initialize())
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }
    this.close()
```

I think sleep helps a lot when you're stuck in a problem.

Comment: I fail to see how this is functionally different to your original client-side code. I suspect you've actually changed something server-side and the original code would actually work now

Comment: Aside from using axios, id is now included in the put method in which it is not included with the first fetch method that I used.

Comment: Wouldn't change the URL at all and so wouldn't fix a 404 response status

Comment: @JimERussel Isn't that sort of exactly what I put in my answer lol? Please accept if it was useful.

Comment: I didn't put an $id in the controller and route. Done.